# images show the name of a button

Tags: android

My app generates random images want the name of the image that is generated is displayed on a button

the images are stored in the drawable folder and their names on a chain. I want the image to appear his name appeared on a button possible?

```js
package com.example.antoniocruz.juegamovil;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Antonio Cruz on 01/06/2015.
 */
public class Categoria extends Activity {

    public static String[] nombre_cosa={"pig " , " bird " , " horse " , " rabbit " , " elephant " , " chicken " , " cat "
            "frog" , "dog" , "duck" , "sheep" , "leon" , " giraffe "
            " Mat" , "cow" , " bus " , " car " , " airplane " , "bicycle" , " truck "
            , "cell " , , , , , , , , "house" , " guitar " , " motorcycle " , " chair " , " television" , " peach " , " strawberry " "mango "
            " grapes " , " watermelon " , " banana " , " coconut " , "pear" , "orange" , "apple "
            " bart " " batman" , "brain" , " guy ", " Goku ", " Homer " " marge "
            " patrician " , " pit " , " Phineas " , " Quico " , " Spiderman ," " Thor" , " superman"};

   
    public static boolean[] estado={false,false,false,false,false,false,
            false,false,false,false,false,false,
            false,false,false,false,false,false,false,
            false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,
            false,false,false,false,false,false,false,
            false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,
            false,false,false,false,false,false};

    public static int cosas_adivinadas=0;
    private int intentos=3;
    private Button aceptar;
    private TextView mensaje_intentos,mensaje_cuenta;
    private EditText usuario_cosa;
    private int numero_generado=0;
    private ImageView miimagen;
    private MediaPlayer reproductor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_categoria);
        aceptar=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnaceptar);
        mensaje_intentos=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblintentos);
        mensaje_cuenta=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblcuenta);
        usuario_cosa=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtcosa);
        miimagen=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgcosa);
        CargarPreferencias();
        new MiTarea().execute();
        reproductor= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.yansha);
        reproductor.setLooping(true);
        reproductor.start();
        mensaje_intentos.setText("Tiene " + intentos + " intentos");
        aceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String nombre=usuario_cosa.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
                if(nombre.equals(nombre_cosa[numero_generado]))
                {
                    establecer_cosa(numero_generado);
                    estado[numero_generado]=true;
                    cosas_adivinadas++;
                    esperar();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrecto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    intentos=intentos-1;
                    mensaje_intentos.setText("Tiene " + intentos + " intentos");
                }

                if (intentos==0)
                {
                    removerPreferencias();
                    Intent i = new Intent(Categoria.this,Perder.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        reproductor.start();
    }

    public void esperar()
    {
        new CountDownTimer(5000,1000)
        {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mensaje_cuenta.setText("Generando en " + (millisUntilFinished/1000));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                if (cosas_adivinadas==nombre_cosa.length)
                {
                    finish();
                }
                else
                {
                    new MiTarea().execute();
                    mensaje_cuenta.setText("");
                    usuario_cosa.setText("");
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void CargarPreferencias()
    {
        SharedPreferences mispreferencias = getSharedPreferences("PreferenciaCosa", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        intentos=mispreferencias.getInt("intentos",3);
        cosas_adivinadas=mispreferencias.getInt("adivinados",0);
        for (int i=0;i<nombre_cosa.length;i++)
        {
            estado[i]=mispreferencias.getBoolean(nombre_cosa[i],false);
        }
    }

    public void GuardarPreferencias()
    {
        SharedPreferences mispreferencias = getSharedPreferences("PreferenciaCosa", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mispreferencias.edit();
        editor.putInt("intentos",intentos);
        editor.putInt("adivinados",cosas_adivinadas);
        for (int i=0;i<nombre_cosa.length;i++)
        {
            editor.putBoolean(nombre_cosa[i], estado[i]);
        }
        editor.commit();
    }

    private void establecer_cosa(int numero)
    {
        int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(nombre_cosa[numero], "drawable", getPackageName());
        miimagen.setImageResource(resId);
    }

    private void establecer_sombra(int numero)
    {
        int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(sombra_cosa[numero], "drawable", getPackageName());
        miimagen.setImageResource(resId);
    }


    private void removerPreferencias()
    {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PreferenciaCosa", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        settings.edit().clear().commit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (intentos==0)
        {
            removerPreferencias();
        }
        else
        {
            GuardarPreferencias();
        }
        reproductor.pause();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (reproductor.isPlaying())
        {
            reproductor.stop();
            reproductor.release();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private class MiTarea extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private int valor_generado;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            do {
                valor_generado=((int)(Math.random()*nombre_cosa.length));
            }while(estado[valor_generado]);
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            numero_generado = valor_generado;
            establecer_sombra(valor_generado);
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: publish it in the question all the full code
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `aceptar` is the `Button` which you talk about, you can just use `.setText()` method to change his text:

```
if(nombre.equals(nombre_cosa[numero_generado])){
    aceptar.setText(nombre_cosa[numero_generado]); //here the change
    establecer_cosa(numero_generado);
    estado[numero_generado]=true;
    cosas_adivinadas++;
    esperar();
}
```

---

**Update**: generate images randomly

1) Create your static arrays:

```
    // your names array
    public static String[] nombre_cosa={"pig " , " bird " , ..., " superman"};

    // your images drawable array
    public static int[] imagenes_cosa= new int[]{R.drawable.pig_image,..., R.drawable.superman_image};
```

2) Create a random position generator method:

```
private int getRandomPosition(){
    Random r = new Random();
    return r.nextInt(nombre_cosa.length);
}
```

3) Set your click listener:

```
    aceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               int randomPosition = getRandomPosition();
               aceptar.setText(nombre_cosa[randomPosition]);
               miimagen.setImageResource(imagenes_cosa[randomPosition]);
            }
        });
```

PS: `nombre_cosa` and `imagenes_cosa` should have the same size!

Comment: thanks for your help I would like to appear on another button the name of the image as possible?

Comment: Of curse, just change the Button name ( "*yourAnotherButton*"  instead of  "*aceptar*" )

Comment: but only if it appears not to give displayable what I want it is to eliminate the EditText so that the name of the image appears on the button

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want. If you need to hide the EditText just change his visibility, otherwise you can add some image/screenshot to describe your problem or what you expect.

Comment: ok I explain further. to guess the images that appear randomly have to write the name on the EditText I would like that instead of typing the name appeared on a button. Appear the image and its respective name on the button

Comment: You want to show your typed  text (of the *EditText* ) in your *Button*?

Comment: Exact you do not have to write the name and the image appears alone on the button.

Comment: In your onClick() method you have to: 1) generate a random number between 0 and your static array size --  2) pick the text from this number to set it in the Button (aceptar.setText (nombre_cosa [yourRandomNumber] ); ) --  3) pick the corresponding image and set it to your ImageView.

Comment: thank you very much if I would bother understanding please show me more or less a clearer example of how it should go

Comment: :( happened a problem with the code I sent first is that I did not put a chain and brand me wrong when I put the code that sent me . I can will publish the full code I well I apologize for that oversight

Comment: you help me now done much I explain further. The app is guess the shade and shadows appear before writing the name in the EditText after giving displayable accept and shadow lit if the answer was correct and went to another image , with your help achieve that the name will be displayed shadow but clicking does not light would appreciate if I could help it in advance thank you very much .

Comment: Hello me again as greetings . I'm still with this little problem with their help if the names appear in the button but pressing the shadow single change does not light shade . The app is something like guess the shadow